# How to find a string in a column with a specific pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains character data that is always of the form:

```
String1/String2|String3|**String4**/String5|String6|String7/String8
```

I would like to retrieve the value of `String4` for each record, but struggling with it.

I noticed that the length of `String1/String2|String3|` is always 48, so I tried doing something like

```
substring (my_field, charindex('String1/String2|String3|',my_field)+48, 20) as **wanted_string**
```

It doesn't quite work as expected, as I am struggling to retain only the string in the `String4` part, and I don't want to hardcode a length value of 48 in it, as it may change over time.

I would appreciate any help to get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String operations are relatively painful in SQL Server.  You can get rid of the first 48 characters using `stuff()` and then take the next delimiter:

```
select left(v.my_field, charindex('|', v.my_field) - 1)
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.my_field, 1, 48, ''))) v(my_field)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(100)='String1/String2|String3|**String4**/String5|String6|String7/String8';

select substring(@s,
--start@:pos 2nd | +1
charindex('|', @s, charindex('|',@s)+1)+1,
charindex('/', @s, charindex('|', @s, charindex('|',@s)+1)) --pos / after 2nd |
-
charindex('|', @s, charindex('|',@s)+1)-1 --subtract start@
);
```